# AOP Logging with custom arguments

Tags: c#, logging, parameters, aop

Before every method executes, I want to log all parameters from that method. For that, I would use AOP (Aspect oriented programming) and create a "Loggable" attribute. But... I also would like to know the content of my parameters. For a string-parameter, that's not a problem. But I would like to know a good solution for every occasion, like objects, ints, doubles,...

Is there any other way to solve this other then to overwrite the ToString() method?
(in examples I always came across a string parameter...)

**Example**:

```
public class MyType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

[Loggable]
public void IDoWhateverIWant(MyType data, int count, string message){
    //Whatever I want
}

IDoWhateverIWant(
       new MyType(){
            Id = 1,
            Name = "My test data name",
            Value = 1234.56}
       , 5
       , "Log me, please");
```

**Logmessage** (the way these parameters are presented are the same to me, I just want to see them):

> 22/07/2014 9:30     Incoming message:     IDoWhateverIWant with parameters:
>                                                   - data : Id = 1
>                                                          Name = "My test data name"
>                                                          Value = 1234.56
>                                                 - count: 5
>                                                 - message: "Log me, please"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option is to use [NewtonSoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to serialize each parameter. This simple example:

```
public void IDoWhateverIWant(MyType data, int count, string message)
{
    string logMessage = 
        ParameterValueMessage(data, "data") + Environment.NewLine +
        ParameterValueMessage(count, "count") + Environment.NewLine +
        ParameterValueMessage(message, "message");

    Debug.Print(logMessage);
}

public static string ParameterValueMessage<T>(T arg, string name)
{
    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg, Formatting.Indented);
    return name + ": " + result;    
}
```

Produces the following:

```
data: {
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "My test data name",
  "Value": 1234.56
}
count: 5
message: "Log me, please"
```

My own preference though is for each method to take a single [parameter object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) - the logging code is a lot neater and more generic with parameter objects and all of the individual parameter names can be inferred from the parameter object:

```
public class MyParameterObject
{
    public MyType data { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

which is serialized in much the same way and has the benefit of not having to pass in the name of every individual parameter:

```
public void IAlsoDoWhateverIWant(MyParameterObject parameterObject)
{
    string logMessage = ParameterValueMessage(parameterObject);

    Debug.Print(logMessage);
}

public static string ParameterValueMessage<T>(T arg)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

and produces the following output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "My test data name",
    "Value": 1234.56
  },
  "count": 5,
  "message": "Log me, please"
}
```